# Vernon's book Implementing DDD

Tags: domain-driven-design

I'm hoping someone has read [Implementing DDD](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321834577) ( Vernon ), since all of my questions reference it

In [article](http://www.infoq.com/articles/ddd-contextmapping) we can see from **Figure 6** that both `BankingAccount` and `PayeeAccount` represent the same underlying concept of *Banking Account* **BA**

**1.** On *page 64* author gives an example of a **publishing organization**, where the life-cycle of a book goes through several stages ( *proposing a book*, *editorial process*, *translation of the book* ... ) and at each of those stages this book has a different definition.

Each stage of the book is defined in a different *Bounded Context*, but do all these different definitions still represent the same *underlying concept* of a **Book**, just like both `BankingAccount` and `PayeeAccount` represent the same *underlying concept* of a **BA**?

**2.**

a) I understand why `User` shouldn't exist in **Collaboration Context** ( CC ), but instead should be defined within **Identity and Access Context** IAC ( page 65 ). But still, do `User` ( IAC ), `Moderator` ( CC ), `Author` ( CC ), `Owner` ( CC ) and `Participant` ( CC ) all represent the same underlying concept of a **Customer**?

b) If yes, doesn't then CC contain several *model elements* ( `Moderator`, `Author`, `Owner` and `Participant` ) which represent the same *underlying concept* of a **Customer**, just like both `BankingAccount` and `PayeeAccount` represent the same *underlying concept* of a **BA**?

c - If `Moderator`, `Author` ... don't represent the *underlying concept* of  **Customer**, then what *underlying concept(s)* do they represent?

**3.** In an **e-commerce system**, the term **Customer** has multiple meanings ( page 49 ): When user is browsing the **Catalog**, **Customer** has different meaning than when user is placing an **Order**.

But do these two different definitions of a **Customer** represent the same *underlying concept*, just like both `BankingAccount` and `PayeeAccount` represent the same *underlying concept* of a BA?

**UPDATE:**

**1.**

> I'd say that they don't have the same concept of book. Your proposal
>   stage probably wont have the concept of a book at all and the
>   editorial process probably wont use the concept of book either,
>   they'll probably refer to a Proposal and a Draft respectively, which
>   would be completely different things to a book.

As far as I can tell, author is implying that the concept of a book will indeed be modeled in all stages?

**2.**

> The concept of Customer isn't mentioned in his example and your
>   e-commerce definition of customer wouldn't fit the model of
>   Moderators, Author, Owner, etc. You'd be best off modelling this
>   around your own distinct business needs.

Perhaps to avoid the confusion, instead of naming the underlying concept a Customer I should use a different name for it, maybe a Consumer. In any case, I used the name Customer for an underlying concept, which I assumed model elements such as User,  Moderator, Author all represent.

**3.**

> The two different meanings of customer in the two different contexts
>   probably wont have a basic underlying type. I doubt that during
>   browsing of the catalogue you'd be interested in the customer's name,
>   address, etc. whereas when placing the order you'd be interested in
>   these things, but less interested in what the last 10 products they
>   visited were.

But the whole point of DDD is that you model selected aspects of reality. In other words, aren't customer's name, address and its browsing history all properties of the same *underlying concept of a Customer*? As such, if the team is working on *Catalog*, it will model only those aspects/properties of an *underlying Customer concept* that are relevant to the browsing ( browsing history ... ), while team working on *placing an order* will model only those aspects of an *underlying Customer concept* that are relevant to placing an order ( address, name ... )?

thanks

Comment: update 3. The selected aspects are dictated by the bounded context(BC). Each is rather autonomous so one BC won't really care about other. The Customer concept is virtual, each BC models its own defition of Customer independently and sometimes all that they have in common is the Customer id. This approach allows to add/remove BC easily without breaking other BC

Answer (score 1):

I'm on the last few pages of the book and it's been a good read.  Personally I'd have liked to see more examples using his 3 fictitious software products.

1. I'd say that they don't have the same concept of book.  Your *proposal* stage probably wont have the concept of a book at all and the *editorial process* probably wont use the concept of book either, they'll probably refer to a Proposal and a Draft respectively, which would be completely different things to a book.
2. The concept of Customer isn't mentioned in his example and your e-commerce definition of customer wouldn't fit the model of Moderators, Author, Owner, etc.  You'd be best off modelling this around your own distinct business needs.
3. The two different meanings of customer in the two different contexts probably wont have a basic underlying type.  I doubt that during browsing of the catalogue you'd be interested in the customer's name, address, etc. whereas when placing the order you'd be interested in these things, but less interested in what the last 10 products they visited were.  The two different context's concepts of Customer might only share a unique Customer id.